# How to access variables in .env file in node.js app heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, environment-variables

I declared variables in a file named `.env`

`MONGOCONNECTIONSTRING=connectionstring`

when I run `heroku local web` it says

`[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format`

I am trying to use the environment variables like this

`const connectionString = process.env.MONGOCONNECTIONSTRING`

in my index.js file

when I try to print the variable connectionstring it is undefined. How do I access the variables.

Heroku's [best practices](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices) say to do that however I must be missing something since the variables are never available.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem

Comment: Hey. I did. I think I used a package called dotenv. I'll check that app and get back to you in a few.

Answer (score 4):

The general practice on Heroku is that you configure your application by setting config vars either via Heroku Dashboard or CLI command. Using CLI is recommended because you can set multiple variables at once:

```
heroku config:set MONGOCONNECTIONSTRING=connectionstring
```

`.env` file should be used only for local development and you shouldn't commit this file to the repository. It is actually mentioned in the docs that you linked.

Also I wonder if you have MongoDB addon provisioned on Heroku? If so, it should set appropriate connection string automatically. Maybe you should check the docs for that.

Comment: I am still testing the node app during development. I am trying to connect to a remote mongodb server when I run heroku local.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I misunderstood your question. And how does your `Procfile` look like?

Comment: `web: node dist/index.js` This is the only thing in it to point to the startup file for the app.

Comment: You can try to output all env variables to see if anything is there `console.log(process.env)`. You can also try to export this variable with `export MONGOCONNECTIONSTRING=connectionstring` or just run `MONGOCONNECTIONSTRING=connectionstring node dist/index.js`.

Comment: Printing the process.env to the console shows the environment variables for my windows computer. I copied it out and it does not contain what I entered in that file. I guess I could put it there in the proc file but wouldn't that defeat the purpose of having the environment variable altogether? The procfile would end up in my version control.

Comment: I meant exporting this only in development, `export` should work best. I know it doesn't solve your problem, but it should allow you to test your app locally.

Comment: Ok I'll try export. Thanks. Where should I write this export statement?

Comment: In your terminal, before starting your application

Answer (score 2):

I found out the issue. The `.env` file was not encoded in `UTF-8`, so the parsing was wrong.